# Speeding up this recursive function

Tags: compile, recursion

I have a recursive function defined like this:

```
Clear[MyFnc];
MyFnc[X_] := Block[{n, val, Xm, Xmn},
    n = Length[X]; If[n == 1, Return[{2, 1}]];
    Xm[mm_] := X[[1 ;; mm]];
    Xmn[mm_, nn_] := X[[mm + 1 ;; nn]];
    val = Table[Block[{XmT = Total[Xm[m]], XmnT = Total[Xmn[m, n]]},
          (XmT.XmnT)/(XmT.XmT)*{m^2, 2 m}*(MyFnc[Xm[m]][[1]])*(MyFnc[Xmn[m,n]][[2]])],
          {m, 1, n - 1}] // Total;
    Return[val/{n^2, n}]];
```

Function takes a list of vectors of arbitrary length $n$, e.g. for $n=5$
and 3D vectors;

```
arg := Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3], {5}]
```

and gives a list of two numbers, i.e. `MyFnc[arg]` gives for 
example `{0.24443, 1.10547}`.

Since this function is to be used as an integrand in numerical 
integration, it would need to be called many times. So evaluation 
time is important,

```
(Table[MyFnc[arg], {10^4}] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]  

(* ==> 18.5959 *)
```

Is there a way to significantly speed up this function?
Can such recursive functions be compiled efficiently?

Comment: It is not possible to compile recursive functions (in general) because the virtual machine does not support recursion (for some reason). However, if the function can be adjusted to become iterative instead of recursive, then it can be compiled.

Comment: I can make it slower by changing `Xmn[m]` to `Xmn[m,n]`.

Comment: It might be a good idea to re-write this function so the argument X is global, and the recursive calls are over the row indices of X.

Comment: @OleksandrR.  `Compile` has handled recursion (with some help needed at times for type inferencing) since around version 7 or maybe 8.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau then why does `With[{fibonacci = Function[Null, If[#1 == 1 || #1 == 2, 1, #0[#1 - 1] + #0[#1 - 2]]]}, Compile[{{i, _Integer, 0}}, fibonacci[i]]]` crash the kernel? Apparently `Compile` is trying to unroll this recursion (the only way the VM can handle it apart from the opcode 43 mechanism, AFAIK) and gets into difficulty. If you are talking about "recursively call out of the VM and instantiate a new VM instance for every call", yes it can handle that, I agree, but I don't think it's useful in most cases because of the huge overhead per call.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau for example instruction 21 of your answer is an opcode 47 call. As far as I understand it, there is no reentrancy here; it is just a new invocation of the VM and will not be compiled any differently if `myFncC` is replaced by any other external call inside `Compile`. So the recursion is happening at the top level; it is not fixed up by `Compile` and it does not occur within the VM. (And, sorry, I should have said opcode 42 in the previous comment, not 43.)

Comment: @OleksandrR. The example you show involves either an outright bug, or unfortunate limitation, of `Compile`. The code that does the compiling gets into recursion itself while trying to unravel that pure function. A simple variation does compile though: fibC = Compile[{{i,_Integer}}, If[i == 1 || i == 2, 1, fibC[i-1]+fibC[i-2]]]

Comment: @OleksandrR. As for `myFncC` it may well be recursing via VM invocations, but clearly they are faster than the usual evaluator. (Also I think you mean opcode 47.) Also, and maybe more importantly, the recursion is not using the OS subroutine stack. It handles 10^6 just fine, which is well beyond what that stack will take.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau yes, exactly--the VM cannot support recursion without re-invoking itself, so `Compile` attempts to unwind the recursion, but crashes because it does not finish after a definite number of steps. If the VM supported recursion directly, `Compile` would not have to perform such acrobatics, but I suppose its design as a register machine does not incorporate a stack, hence the problem. The opcode 43 mechanism is a slightly less indirect method of recursion than the opcode 47 one--it involves two `LibraryLink` functions compiled together. Then the recursion is done in C.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `test = Compile[{{n, _Integer, 0}}, If[n == 0, 1, test[n - 1]]]; test[10^6]` crashes the kernel as well. It has clearly blown the stack, even if it doesn't produce any `reclim` messages. It dies somewhere around `n == 4.8*^4`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I should add that this is important because the top-level version of exactly the same function (i.e. without using `Compile`/the VM) is **tail recursive** and will not blow the stack no matter how large `n` gets. I have to stand by my previous statement that the VM does not support recursion in any truly useful sense.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Okay, I see the issue. Yes, `Compile` apparently does not support tail recursion, and my remarks about subroutine stack behavior were incorrect. Though I am not convinced that shortcoming makes it less than useful for recursion in general.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it through `Compile` as below. Note that I have not tested for correctness.

```
myFncC = Compile[{{X, _Real, 2}}, Block[
    {n, val},
    n = Length[X];
    If[n == 1, Return[{2., 1.}]];
    val = Total[
      Table[
       Block[
        {XmT = Total[X[[1 ;; m]]], XmnT = Total[X[[m + 1 ;; n]]], 
         mFm = myFncC[X[[1 ;; m]]], mFmn = myFncC[X[[m + 1 ;; n]]]},
        (XmT.XmnT)/(XmT.XmT)*{m^2, 2 m}*mFm[[1]]*mFmn[[2]]], {m, 1, 
        n - 1}]];
    val/{n^2, n}]];

arg := Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3], {5}]
(Table[myFncC[arg], {10^4}] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]

(* Out[67]= 1.13199 *)
```

Adding `"CompilationTarget" -> "C"` brings it down a hair more, to .75 seconds.