# Compiled function and integration

Tags: numerical-integration, compile

I'm using the recursive functions defined [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/104346/speeding-up-this-recursive-function?noredirect=1#comment283270_104346): `MyFnc` and `myFncC` (compiled version). I want to call this functions in the integration rutine, so I first defined:

```
MyFncC[Q_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := myFncC[Q];
```

Compiled version indeed performs faster which can be checked as:

```
arg := Table[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 3], {5}]
arg2 = arg;

(Table[MyFnc[arg2], {10^3}] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
(*Out[]  1.77652 *)
(Table[myFncC[arg2], {10^3}] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
(*Out[]  0.27442 *)
(Table[MyFncC[arg2], {10^3}] // AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
(*Out[]  0.24558 *)
```

Not sure why the `MyFncC` is faster than `myFncC` one, but ok...

Now I want to do the numerical integrals using the `MyFnc`:

```
Int[x_] := Block[{INT, FNC, xx, yy, y, phi},
           xx = {0., 0., x};
           yy = {y*Sin[phi], 0., y*Cos[phi]};
           FNC = (MyFnc[{xx, yy, xx - yy}][[1]])*y^2 Exp[-y^2];
           INT = NIntegrate[FNC , {y, 0.01, 10.0}, {phi, 0, Pi}, PrecisionGoal -> 5, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
           Return[INT]];
```

and similarly using the `MyFncC`;

```
CInt[x_] := Block[{INT, FNC, xx, yy, y, phi},
            xx = {0., 0., x};
            yy = {y*Sin[phi], 0., y*Cos[phi]};
            FNC = (MyFncC[{xx, yy, xx - yy}][[1]])*y^2 Exp[-y^2];
            INT = NIntegrate[FNC , {y, 0.01, 10.0}, {phi, 0, Pi},PrecisionGoal -> 5,Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
            Return[INT]];
```

In order to evaluate the preformance I look at:

```
(Table[{x, Int[x]}, {x, 0.001, 1.0, 0.005}]//AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
(*Out[]  7.97999 *)
(Table[{x, CInt[x]}, {x, 0.001, 1.0, 0.005}]//AbsoluteTiming)[[1]]
(*Out[]  8.12214 *)
```

And annoyingly the `CInt` version that uses the compiled version is 
actually slower. Why is that?

More generally, would I be better of writing a brute force MC integration using `CInt` then using NIntegrate? 
I eventually want to go beyond the 2D integration.

**Some potentially useful info**

Something seems to be problematic related to symbolic processing, since 
when running the `CInt` error message appears, e.g.

```
 CInt[0.3]
 (* CompiledFunction::cfta: Argument {{0.,0.,0.3},{y Sin[phi],0.,y Cos[phi]},{0. -y Sin[phi],0.,0.3 -y Cos[phi]}} 
    at position 1 should be a rank 2 tensor of machine-size real numbers. >> *)
 (*Out[] -0.318841 *)
```

but I don't understand why this happens. I thought using `MyFncC` instead  of `myFncC` should have resolved this.

I also realised that somewhat similar problems have been addressed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82817/nintegrate-ing-a-compiled-function).
I've tried to check the number of evaluations by replacing the 
`INT` line in the integrals with something like;

```
INT = Length@Last@Last@Reap@NIntegrate[FNC , {y, 0.01, 10.0}, {phi, 0, Pi}, 
      PrecisionGoal -> 5, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
      EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[0]];
```

and this gives the same number of evaluations for both `Int` and `CInt`, e.g.

```
Int[0.3]
(*Out[] 7871 *)
CInt[0.3]
(*Out[] 7871 *)
```

so `CInt` is not slower because it does more evaluations.